# Spring data JPA PSQLException using @Query and @Modifying

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa (Version 2.0.4.RELEASE) and PostgreSQL (Version 9.5.10), I keep getting the **PSQLException**: No results were returned by the query, though I did use `@Modifying` as proposed by many others here. Adding `@Transactional` as suggested by some, didn't make a difference either.
Analyzing the StackTrace one could see that `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery()` is called, whereas `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` should be called. 
What can I do?

```
@Repository
public interface Rank extends JpaRepository<RankArticle, String> {

@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE rank SET id=calc.id, shop_id=calc.shop_id, " +
                "score=calc.score, rank = calc.rank FROM " +
                    "(SELECT id, shop_id, SUM(sales) AS score, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS rank " +
                    "FROM " +
                        "(SELECT id, sales, shop_id FROM daily_pod " +
                        "WHERE shop_id = :shopId " +
                        "UNION " +
                        "SELECT id, sales, shop_id FROM weekly_pod " +
                        "WHERE shop_id = :shopId " +
                        "UNION " +
                        "SELECT id, sales, shop_id FROM end_pod " +
                        "WHERE shop_id = :shopId) " +
                    "AS pods " +
                    "GROUP BY id, shop_id ORDER BY score DESC limit :limit) as calc;"
        , nativeQuery = true)
void calcScore(@Param("shopId") Integer shopId,
               @Param("limit") Integer limit);
```

}

> EDIT: Add Full Stack-Trace:
>
> ```
> [ERROR] 2018-09-20 17:49:10,503 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [d.t.p.v.backend.VerkaufsrangConfig] - Konnte AMQP-Nachricht nicht
> ```
>
> verarbeiten!
>         org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException:
>   Listener method 'public void
>   de.thalia.pim.verkaufsrang.backend.application.rabbitmq.SalesHandler.receive(org.springframework.amqp.core.Message)'
>   threw exception
>          at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190)
>          at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
>              at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414)
>                at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337)
>              at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324)
>          at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303)
>             at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817)
>             at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801)
>               at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77)
>             at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042)
>             at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>         Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract
>   ResultSet
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314)
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
>            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
>                at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
>               at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
>             at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>          at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
>            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>           at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>               at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>              at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>              at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.calcScore(Unknown Source)
>               at de.thalia.pim.verkaufsrang.backend.business.SalesRankService.calculateRank(SalesRankService.java:28)
>           at de.thalia.pim.verkaufsrang.backend.application.rabbitmq.SalesHandler.receive(SalesHandler.java:60)
>             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>           at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
>          at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:51)
>             at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:182)
>             ... 10 common frames omitted
>         Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
>          at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168)
>               at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
>            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
>             at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
>          at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
>              at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
>          at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
>                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
>              at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
>          at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2200)
>             at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
>               at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
>          at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
>          at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:380)
>            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.getResultList(Unknown Source)
>             at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
>                at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
>              at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
>          at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
>              at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
>            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>           at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>          at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>             at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>          at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>             at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>          ... 29 common frames omitted
>         Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
>             at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
>             at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>              at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
>           ... 63 common frames omitted

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace

Comment: Have you tried to execute your query in a SQL editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by changing the statement into an INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT (...) DO UPDATE one:

```
@Transactional
public interface Rank extends CrudRepository<RankArticle, Identity> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO rank" +
                        "(SELECT id, shop_id, SUM(sales) AS score, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS rank " +
                        "FROM " +
                            "(SELECT id, shop_id, sales FROM daily_pod " +
                            "WHERE shop_id = :shopId " +
                            "UNION " +
                            "SELECT id, shop_id, sales FROM weekly_pod " +
                            "WHERE shop_id = :shopId " +
                            "UNION " +
                            "SELECT id, shop_id, sales FROM end_pod " +
                            "WHERE shop_id = :shopId) " +
                        "AS pods " +
                        "GROUP BY id, shop_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT :limit) " +
                "ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE " +
                "SET shop_id = EXCLUDED.shop_id, score = EXCLUDED.score, " +
                    "rank_count = EXCLUDED.rank_count;"
        , nativeQuery = true)
void calcScore(@Param("shopId") Integer shopId,
               @Param("limit") Integer limit);
```

}